# .net hide implementation and provide interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I am working with several developers who develop .net components for me.

I manage the licensing mechanism and want to hide the implementation.

I would like to just provide them the interface, with for example the `methodIsLicenseValid()` so they must use it in the code but cannot access the implementation.

Which pattern or technology should I use to reach that objective?

Comment: Dependency injection maybe, that way you could provide the interface to the devs, and your implementation can be in a separate lib and resolve in the bindings at runtime.

Comment: Is there some performance issues known with DI? And do I have to use unity for that of there is another way to set it through app.config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a `Web Service` to expose the `methodIsLicenseValid()`, and let your devs invoke it whenever necessary.

This will be suitable for your production environment anyways and also will allow you to change the implementation of the methodIsLicenseValid(), without causing hasles to the devs, as opposed to providing a library/dll to them

Comment: Just as a comment, it need not be a web service, any service, regardless of communication mechanism will do. For example a TCP WCF service may be preferable for in-house scenarios due to better performance.

Comment: I am wondering if my final customer will like that he needs to have a F2F service installed on his servers, because I am looking for an offline licensing mechanism.

Comment: In that case you might have to go with providing a lib/dll, but is your customer's environment not connected to the internet?

Comment: I would like to impose an online license validation at the installation time, and encrypt the license locally. After, every time the application is used, it should check if the license is valid. I want to hide the implementation of that check.to my customers by obfuscation but also to hide it to my developer