# .NET Application - How to hide implementation of dependent libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, class-library

This can be possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151771/net-hide-implementation-and-provide-interface) question, but I don't want to go with solution suggested i.e. use of Web Service.

*Here is the scenario:*

1) I want to expose one class library to clients. Let's name it "MyClassLibrary".

2) There are two more libraries "Library1" and "Library2" in the same solution for "MyClassLibrary" project.

3) "Libray1" is referred in "Library2" and "Library2" is referred in "MyClassLibrary".

4) There is no direct reference of "Libray1" inside "MyClassLibrary".

***What do I want?***

Client of "MyClassLibrary" should not be able to access classes, methods in "Library1". Is it ever possible? If I create nuget package for "MyClassLibrary", it will contain dll for "Library1" (as well as "Library2"). So using that dll, client can easily access stuff in "Library1" (as well as in "Library2"). How can I avoid that? I want my client to be able to access only required functions from "MyClassLibrary" and not implementation of "Library1" (and maybe "Library2"). How to achieve this?

Comment: @Hameed, If classes in "Library1" or "Library2" are private, I will not be able to access them in "MyClassLibrary" even. So access modifier is not going to work.

Comment: Does anything else use libraries 1 and 2?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, there could be some other libraries as well which use libraries 1 and 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make it less convenient for your client to access your code, you could use access specifiers to prevent him from doing so. For example you could use the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to hide your implementation, or put it all in one single assembly and make most of it private.

However, this is just to prevent him from accidentally using it.

If it contains secrets that you don't want him to know, you *must not* deliver it to him. One option would be to only deliver the interface of a webservice and have the actual service with your secrets run at your location. If you give him the assemblies, no mater how well protected, obfuscated or otherwise obscured, your secret is in the open.

Comment: These are some good suggestion from you. I will give them a try and will accept your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Making things `internal` solves the problem you just described. As well, be aware of existence of `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo(...)]`.

Surely, rightly applied reflection makes even private things accessible. But I don't consider such a case.

Comment: If classes in "Library1" or "Library2" are internal, I will not be able to access them in "MyClassLibrary".

Comment: Pay attention to the attribute I've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Sereja, I will consider using [assembly:InternalsVisibleTo(...)].